# Is sailsjs - waterline can support mongodb in a smart way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I've been looking at sailsjs lately and by looking at the documenation http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Models.html
especailly this:

```
    // From api/models/Person.js...

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    // Primitive attributes
    firstName: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: ''
    },
    lastName: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: ''
    },

    // Associations (aka relational attributes)
    spouse: { model: 'Person' },
    pets: { collection: 'Pet' },

    // Attribute methods
    getFullName: function (){
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    },
    isMarried: function () {
      return !!this.spouse;
    },
    isEligibleForSocialSecurity: function (){
      return this.age >= 65;
    },
    encryptPassword: function () {

    }
  }
};
```

It seems like heavy sql minded, how can I have attributes that are array of objects? like mongodb.

For example maybe my Person model has an attribute called liked_movies which is an array of movies that each movie has its own name and length

Answer (score 3):

You should use model associations.
[Salis docs about associations](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations)

In the example of the movies you are asking, a [**many to many**](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/ManytoMany.html) association will do. Sails will create the pivot table for you. It will also create a REST like url for that association. i.e `person/:personId/likedMovies`